# ¿Cómo hacer un calendario en tkinter - tkcalendar- python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Quisiera pedir ayuda como un usuario nuevo de python
Quiero hacer un calendario para capturar rangos de fechas pero sólo meses o años. Tengo como fecha de inicio en febrero de 2007 hasta el mes actual para seleccionar archivos mensuales (hay algunos meses que no tengo archivos, que no hay datos, pero eso es un paso posterior de validación que significa cargar (o actualizar esos meses según corresponda) esos meses que no están usando un calendario similar). Con esos rango crear una lista para que ejecute otras rutinas.

Dejo dos imágenes (calendario windows) de como debería mostrarse el calendario para que seleccione desde 1 o más meses. La idea es seleccionar desde mes1 y año1 a otro mes2 y año2 (considerando que mes1 puede ser igual mes2 y año1 puede ser igual año2). Luego de seleccionar generar una lista (o dos) con mes1 y mes2 y año1 y año2. Y además mostrar en la ventana el periodo seleccionado (posibilidad de reselección)

Gracias por la ayuda para un usuario nuevo en Python.

Pd: no pongo código porque no sé si se puede hacer con tkcalendar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: La [documentación](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Calendar.html#doc) no muestra que esto sea posible a través de argumentos. Si querés lograr eso, podés modificar la fuente de tkcalendar para adaptarlo a tu necesidad o crear tu propio widget. Alternativamente, podrías usar de tapabaches que solo se pueda seleccionar del 1 de febrero de 2007 hasta la fecha de hoy e indicar en la interfáz que los días no se tienen en cuenta. De ahí, podés trabajar con los atributos date.month y date.year para el mes y año respectivamente.

Comment: Si no, te toca buscar otro módulo que te permita crear un calendario en Tkinter y cumpla ese requisito

Comment: Gracias @DanteS.  Creo trataré de buscar otro módulo dado que [tkcalendar](https://pypi.org/project/tkcalendar/#history)  esta sin soporte o abandonado, la úktima versión es de diciembre de 2019. Y así lo comentan otros usuarios [issues](https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar/issues/100). Respecto de tus otras sugerencias "modificar la fuente de tkcalendar para adaptarlo a tu necesidad o crear tu propio widget.", mis conocimientos son inmensamente pobres para intentarlo (no sé por dónde iniciar). Gracias nuevamente. Si tienes una sugerencia de otro modulo se agradece.

Comment: Entiendo. No conosco ninguna librería, pero que te vaya bien!